# Error installing CouchDB with homebrew osx 10.8 - skip dependency?

Tags: erlang, couchdb, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew

So I tried to install it [according to the directions](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_on_OSX#If_you.27ve_brewed_CouchDB_before) on couchdb wiki.  and I get the following issue

```
Installing couchdb dependency: erlang-r15
==> Downloading https://github.com/erlang/otp/archive/OTP_R15B03-1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/erlang-r15-R15B03-1.tar.gz
Error: SHA1 mismatch
Expected: 5ba866722de79956b06966c232490d32bb7ba0a6
Actual: 7843070f5d325f95ef13022fc416b22b6b14120d
Archive: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/erlang-r15-R15B03-1.tar.gz
```

Is there anyway to tell brew to skip this dependency since I have already installed the correct version of erlang, and it can't see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to get this working  I followed the instruction on the couchdb until the install couchdb command:

```
brew remove --force openssl erlang couchdb icu4c spidermonkey nspr
brew update
brew outdated
brew rm --force erlang
cd /usr/local
git checkout 168742f Library/Formula/erlang.rb
brew install erlang
```

since I knew I had the right erlang installed I altered the Bew formula to make it work correctly.
So I headed over to the formula at

```
vim /usr/local/Library/Formula/couchdb.rb
```

And altered the dependency line

```
depends_on 'erlang-15'
```

to

```
depends_on 'erlang'
```

and works great now!!

Comment: This total messed my system up, I should have looked at the date  You should have added a *`brew missing`* in there so not to delete dependencies

Comment: Sorry pixel!  Any chance you could update the answer with the right code? I haven't used brew missing before, and couldn't find the documentation easily.  Thanks!

Comment: sorry, I can't get couchdb installed since I updated to maverick

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `brew uninstall couchdb` and re install after?
I had the same issue, it fixed it for me

Comment: Sadly no it didn't work because it never was installed to begin with but I did figure a work around.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions here worked for me, but the below did. Note, I had to build [with unixodbc](https://github.com/iriscouch/build-couchdb/issues/94#issuecomment-27160850).

```
brew remove --force openssl erlang couchdb icu4c spidermonkey
brew update
brew install unixodbc
brew install homebrew/versions/erlang-r15 --with-unixodbc
# edit /usr/local/Library/Formula/couchdb.rb to change depends_on to 'erlang-r15'
brew install couchdb
```

You may want to first try force removing only erlang and couchdb -- as someone in this thread mentioned that force removing packages messed up his system (though I did not encounter this problem when running the above instructions).